# How to get only the TAGS of a PRODUCT in view.phtml in Magento 1.7.0.2?

Tags: php, magento, tags

I need to get **only the TAGS** of the product that I am viewing in the **product page** meaning `view.phtml`

If I use this command

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
```

I get NOT only the tags but the whole information related of the product.

How can I break the **product_additional_data** to tags,reviews etc ???
What are the related commands for getting ONLY the tags or gettings ONLY the reviews?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello add below code in view.phtml

```
<?php
// instantiate the tags class for products
$_tags = new Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List();
?>

<ul class="product-tags">
<?php foreach($_tags->getTags() as $tag):?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $tag->getTaggedProductsUrl()?>"><?php echo $tag->getName()?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: But in magento 1.9.2 its not working, is there a different way or how do i get this.