# how to get Product Tag id

Tags: magento, module, tags, magento-1.9, php

I want to get 8 product using by tag how to get current product tag id.

```
    $tagId = 1; // I want to get id on view.html 
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addTagFilter($tagId);
    print_r($collection->getData());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two way to put limit on collection.

```
 $tagId = 1; // I want to get id on view.html 
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addTagFilter($tagId)
        ->setPageSize(8);
```

**or**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addTagFilter($tagId);
$collection->getSelect()->limit(8);
```

Comment: thanks for help, but i want tagId dynamic only get those tag id related to product

Comment: see this  question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742046/how-to-get-only-the-tags-of-a-product-in-view-phtml-in-magento-1-7-0-2

Comment: its fine but can I use array in ->addTagFilter($tagId);

Comment: yes you can pass array

Comment: ->addTagFilter('tag_id', array('in' => $tag_id_array)); -- not working

Comment: addAttributeToFilter use this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Qaisar for help

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after `addProductFilter` from `Mage_Tag_Model_Entity_Customer_Collection`

```
$model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->getCollection()
    ->addProductFilter($ProductId)
    ->setFlag('relation', true)
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->setActiveFilter();
```